# Actualización de versiones de los archivos JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hago uso de **JQuery** en mi sitio, además del archivo *.css* tengo dos archivos JavaScript, los cuales son (**/jquery.js** y **/jquery-ui.min.js**). Hace mucho que están y todo funciona perfecto. Ahora se me dio por probar mi sitio con la herramienta *Lighthouse* y ver las mejores que se le pueden hacer. En una categoría que llaman "Mejores prácticas" me sale que: "Se incluye bibliotecas de JavaScript front-end con vulnerabilidades de seguridad conocidas" y al ver más detalles dice: "Algunos scripts de terceros pueden contener vulnerabilidades de seguridad conocidas que los atacantes pueden identificar y explotar fácilmente." Para luego mostrarme lo siguiente:
`jQuery@1.10.2 Mayor gravedad: Medio
jQuery UI@1.11.4 Mayor gravedad: Alto`

Entiendo que hay que actualizar estas librerías. Pero se me presentan algunas dudas. Me acuerdo de la librería `jQuery UI@1.11.4` que sería la **jquery-ui.min.js** entonces entrando a la página de https://jqueryui.com/ veo que allí aparece para descargar la versión **1.12.1**, pero claro al descargar te pone varias cosas en una carpeta (la cual se llama **jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom**), además de la **jquery-ui.min.js** (con la versión **1.12.1**) y los estilos (*jquery-ui.min.css*), dentro hay otras carpetas que se llaman **/external/jquery** y allí adentro el archivo **jquery.js**. Acá viene mi duda, quiero creer que ese archivo **jquery.js** (con su última versión) sería el que yo tengo como **/jquery.js** y debo reemplazar, o sea, el que *Lighthouse* me pone como `jQuery@1.10.2`. Sí abro el archivo nuevo **jquery.js**, veo que dice al principio como comentario "jQuery JavaScript Library v1.12.4".

La pregunta, en definitiva, es el tema de las versiones. Es que si abro el `jQuery@1.10.2` que me sale en *Lighthouse*, siendo este un link, me lleva a una página que me dice que hay que **actualizar a la versión 3.3.1** y en ningún lado veo que diga eso (en los archivos que descargo), sólo me sale "jQuery JavaScript Library v1.12.4" como ya comente.

A lo mejor hablar de la **versión 3.3.1** es lo mismo que **1.12.4** en el archivo **jquery.js**. Siempre lo descargue desde la página https://jqueryui.com/ por eso no comprendo lo de la versión **3.3.1**. Sino para no romper mi sitio voy a tener que dejar todo como hasta hora y sin actualizar, ya que están funcionando.

Comment: Leí todo y no entendí cuál es la pregunta o problema, ¿podrías editar la pregunta y agregar un «problema o pregunta puntual»?

Comment: En concreto, ¿es lo mismo la versión 1.12.4 que la 3.3.1? La 3.3.1 es la que dicen desde aca <https://snyk.io/vuln/npm:jquery?lh=1.10.2&utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=ref&utm_campaign=audit>

Answer (score 3):

Respondiendo a la pregunta entregada por el OP en los comentarios: **¿es lo mismo la versión 1.12.4 que la 3.3.1?**

La respuesta es **NO**, no son la misma versión.

---

Según el repositorio de jQuery en GitHub (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/releases), la versión 3.3.1 fue lanzada el 20 de enero de 2018, mientras que la versión 1.12.4 fue lanzada el 20 de mayo de 2016.

Aunque la fecha de lanzamiento no es determinante, si lo es probablemente el cambio de versión mayor (de 1.x a 3.x), por lo cual podríamos concluir que no son la misma versión.

Al realizar la comparación de los tags en GitHub, encontramos que hay 1450 commits  entre las dos versiones y hubo cambios en 312 archivos, por lo cual seguramente no son la misma versión. Fuente: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/compare/1.12.4...3.3.1

---

Por último, en el blog oficial de jQuery están los posts respectivos (en inglés) del lanzamiento de dichas versiones, cuyas fechas de publicación (de los posts) coinciden con las fechas de los releases en GitHub.

> jQuery 3.3.1: https://blog.jquery.com/2018/01/20/jquery-3-3-1-fixed-dependencies-in-release-tag/
>
> jQuery 1.12.4: https://blog.jquery.com/2016/05/20/jquery-1-12-4-and-2-2-4-released/

Podrías revisar todos los cambios realizados entre estas dos versiones en sus respectivos posts en el blog, pasando por algunas versiones de 2.x y todas las de 3.x

Comment: (para el OP) en cuanto a jQuery de la versión 1.x a la 3.x el cambio es considerable ya que hay cosas que simplemente dejaron de existir como `size()`, recomiendo hacer pruebas con el cambio de esta librería, para jquery ui me parece que no es mucho el cambio

Comment: @LPZadkiel si puedes elaborar más al respecto sobre los cambios importantes entre las dos versiones, puedes agregar todo a la respuesta que eliminaste para que complemente lo que ya respondí, dicha información también es útil.

Comment: pues en este momento no lo recuerdo, además creo que el vínculo del blog de jquery 3.1.1 que pusiste tendrá todo lo que necesita saber. Lo que si recuerdo es que tuve problemas con librerías anexas que ocupaban jquery antiguo y al actualizar me fallaron cosas al punto que tuve que ir a cambiar el código de esas librerías, muchas librerías usan jQuery y al hacer cambio de versión probablemente se encuentre con ese tipo de problemas y quería que supiese que el hacer el cambio de versión le puede tomar mas tiempo y problemas del que piensa aunque si el cambio de versión es necesario por seguridad

Comment: ¿No me sirve descargar sólo los archivos .js desde <https://jqueryui.com/download/>? y donde cuya versión son 1.12.1. Yo creía que allí mismo ya venía actualizado el archivo _jquery.js_ (está en la carpeta de descarga y supuestamente es el más actual). Entonces, de no ser así, ¿en donde está para descargar la versión 3.3.1? o si me pueden decir exactamente desde donde descargar bien todo, mucho mejor. Estoy medio perdido.